# Published app displaying default system fonts instead of customized fonts

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My published Windows Phone 8 app is not showing the fonts which used in the project. In the emulator, it shows me the correct fonts. But after actually downloading the app from store, it displays the default system fonts. I used XAML/C# to make this app and used the fonts like this:

```
FontFamily="/Fonts/BOOKOS.TTF#Bookman Old Style"
```

I placed the fonts in the 'Fonts' folder. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Did you test it on the physical device before submitting to the store?

Comment: No. I do not own a Windows Phone 8 device. But it worked in emulator. In my friends phone though (he downloaded the app from the store), it didn't.

Comment: You did include the fonts in your project right?

Comment: Have you checked the build action of the font file?

Comment: @Cloud9999Strife : Yea of course lol

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal : build action of the font file? what is that..? please elaborate.

Comment: Or you guys can just tell me how you all include fonts in your Windows Phone apps.. is it the same way I do or if it is something different. Your method may work for me too..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The font that I was using were not embeddable. I then used some open-source fonts from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) and they were displayed on the device too. This doesn't happen if the font used is not Embeddable. Generally fonts from Adobe doesn't integrate with the app. So either use an open-source font or buy a font with its license.

Answer (score 0):

your method was just perfect. just make a folder 'Fonts' in your solution and include you font in that, now right click on the file and go to its property. There in the properties you will find a property named Build action, just set it to content.